# Can I access all images in a .xcassets at once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcasset

I have a big amount of images in a Images.xcassets and I need to load them all in a UITableView. But I don't wat to write each name for the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]`.

What i'm looking for is something like:

```
NSArray *images = [MagicClass loadAllImagesIn:@"images.xcassets"];
```

Do you know if this is even possible? If not maybe i'll create a .bundle...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Images.xcassets` copies all the images in bundle, and it mixes up with other images, better follow the instructions in image below

[image]

By adding the folder with the option `Create folder reference` will actually create a folder in main bundle with its content, and all your images will be separated. And using the following code you can access all the images.

```
NSString *dirPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
NSError * error;
NSArray * images =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:&error];
```

Hope it helps.