# How to save HTML file with all external resources to disk on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I know how to save single html file to disk, but are there any tools that save all external resources (such as js scripts, images, css files) to disk so I can load HTML later without internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389720/can-i-access-all-images-in-a-xcassets-at-once/24390080#24390080)  and look for how to add a `blue folder`.. Put your all the resources in a folder and add that folder the way described in the link.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I need to load HTML pages with external resources in run time from the internet

Comment: Your question says you want it without internet, so get all the resources for the HTML page, is it a dynamic html link?

Comment: YES. Load html resources from the internet when it's reachable, and load from disk cache when it's not reachable.