# How To Read Images From NSMainBundle in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, resourcebundle, nsbundle

I have the structure like the following in my Xcode project.

[image]

I need to read all the images from project and need to store it in array.

I have used the following code from some other StackOverflow posts, but it's not working.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images"ofType:@""];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum;
direnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath: filePath];
imageFolder = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString *filename in direnum){
    if([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]){
        [imageFolder addObject:filename];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Files in the folder %@",imageFolder);
```

I would appreciate, if any one help me to complete this.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389720/can-i-access-all-images-in-a-xcassets-at-once/24390080#24390080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (NSArray *)pathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath` will get you the array you want.

```
NSArray *imagesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"];
```

Answer (score 2):

it's simple to get all the images into a array

```
NSBundle *imageBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath: myBundlePath];
NSArray *allImageURLs=[imageBundle URLsForResourcesWithExtension:@"png" subdirectory:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];

[pathArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *pathString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    UIImage *yourImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathString];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, hope it will work.

```
    NSString *dirPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * images =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:&error];
```